# 500 error on new WP install on multi-site, staging server

Tags: wordpress, multisite, staging, http-status-code-500

I'm working for a client that has a multi-site server, which hosts about 5 live sites. Within that, he also has a "staging server" where we are trying to re-design one of the existing 5 sites.

I have installed WP in a sub-directory (/fb) on this staging server (it has to be in a sub-directory for now). When I browsed the URL, it gave me a 404. I was told I needed to edit my hosts file on my PC to point the domain to the staging server. So, I did that. Now instead of a 404, it's giving me a 500 error.

I've tried everything I can think of/find to get this to work, but to no avail. Here is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fb/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /fb/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I've also increased PHP limit and attempted to enable debug mode.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I only have cPanel access to the staging site, not the live site.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just have a cpanel access you can not do much more about this issue. Contact your hosting provider support and they will be able to help you out with the issue since they have full root access which is need to check on the error logs while browsing the website.